# Is it possible to inject NODE_ENV param into sass file using Webpack & sass loader?

Tags: sass, webpack, libsass, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

I'm trying to inject NODE_ENV into a sass file, so I can have different output for dev/prod env, and have a sass function that has a condition like that inside it:
`@if (NODE_ENV == 'prod') {}`

my webpack.config looks like this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style-loader!raw-loader!sass-loader?includePaths[]=" + path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib")
    }]
}
```

I tried passing a data parameter to the loader, but nothing that I tried worked.
will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7):

this is the code directly from sass-loader repo.

**webpack.config.js**

`...
sassLoader: {
   data: "$env: " + process.env.NODE_ENV + ";"
}
...`

Comment: Can I do this without eject my app?

Answer (score 3):

## You can try the `prependData` option for `sass-loader`

```
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
  }
}
```

`prependData` also accepts a `function` which receives the `loaderContext` with which you can make it more dynamic.  Once you have implemented this; you can :

```
@if ($env == 'prod') {}
```

More information here : https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#prependdata

Good Luck...

Comment: Can I do this without `eject` my app?

Comment: Hi @FabianoLothor,  can you please alaborate your question?

Comment: using create-react-app I cannot config webpack manually, it is pre-configured. I can set up webpack only if I decide to eject the app.

Comment: @FabianoLothor, you may try [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco). Reference blog : [Customize Webpack Config](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc).  Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the `sass-loader` source and it doesn't seem to support any options that would allow you to insert a variable -- so it won't be possible this way.

I don't think you'll be able to 'insert' an env/build-time variable into your Sass like this, but you could get the same behavior by creating multiple Sass files and requiring the one you want (from your js source) based on a condition. Note that webpack has limited ability to parse the logic in your code, however -- if you want to `require` something within a conditional, the conditional has to check a boolean value for it to work. So if you do `if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {...} else {...}` webpack will process all the requires in all those conditions. If you did something like `if (IS_PROD_ENV) {...} else {...}`, where the conditional value is a boolean, webpack will follow the conditional logic and only process the correct `require`. The `UglifyJS` plugin will remove the unneeded conditional branches for you.